# blank images in firefox

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, skype

I have Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 (64 bit) in Linux Mint 17 - 64bit

Symptom is that some images doesn't load.

For example, when I try to access whatsapp web I get this instead of the QR code.

[image: Whatsapp issue 1]

and before I could copy an image and paste it in whatsapp web or skype web, but now when I paste the image I get a blank rectangle.

Already tried another browser and refreshing firefox. Could you please guide me through the troubleshooting.

EDIT #1: I just checked that if I refresh the page, the QR code flashes por less than 1 second until it dessapears.

[image: Here you can see how the error ocurrs.]

Comment: Do you have a regular web page where such an image problem occurs? Your example might not be a good one, because the generated QR code image might involve other interactions than just displaying an image (presuming the code is unique, anyway).

Comment: It happened in Skype, when I have an image in the clipboard and paste (Ctrl + V) it in a chat window.